# jar file works in eclipse folder but not out of it.Main class notfound

Tags: java, groovy, ant

My groovy (ant1.8.1 for build)project was build in jdk1.5 and now i am making some changes and upgrading to jdk1.8 .
When i build and make jar ,it works fine from the folder where code is in eclipse.
but when copy that jar and try to run get below-

```
Error :could not find or load main class Run.
```

Rest all jars are as below(same as used in jdk5)

```
 groovy-all-1.6.9.jar
 commons-codec-1.4.jar
 commons-httpclient-3.0-rc4.jar 
 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar 
 commons-net-2.0.jar 
 lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar
 jtds-1.2.5.jar
 httpmime-4.0.1.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "run", I understand you mean something like:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

You should check your MANIFEST file inside the JAR and make sure your Main-Class is defined as you need.

```
Main-Class: pakage.name.ClassName.class
```

And the corresponding `pakage.name.ClassName.class` exists in your jar file (or is included in any of the libraries accessible through classpath)
Check this anyway [Setting application entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)